# Error in building MM2 using phonegap build

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, moodle, moodle-mobile

I'm trying to create a custom app from MM2 based on this presentation from Juan Leyva:
https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1HX5h7zwtay4amaY3qyLuCLfI7kQCiD9IoWuDH-lSa_0/edit#slide=id.ga20278994_0_101

I customized and was able to successfully run emulation using ionic
But when I try to build my android version using phonegap build (http://build.phonegap.com) I get these errors

```
Build Date: 2016-05-25 14:42:44 +0000

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'project'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/support-v4-23.4.0.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/support-v4-23.4.0.jar
         file:/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/support-v4-23.4.0.pom
         file:/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/support-v4-23.4.0.jar
         file:/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/support-v4-23.4.0.pom
         file:/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/support-v4-23.4.0.jar
     Required by:
         :project:unspecified
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/support-v4-23.4.0.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/support-v4-23.4.0.jar
         file:/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/support-v4-23.4.0.pom
         file:/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/support-v4-23.4.0.jar
         file:/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/support-v4-23.4.0.pom
         file:/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/support-v4-23.4.0.jar
     Required by:
         :project:unspecified > com.android.support:support-v13:23.2.1
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/support-v4-23.4.0.pom
         https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/support-v4-23.4.0.jar
         file:/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/support-v4-23.4.0.pom
         file:/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/support-v4-23.4.0.jar
         file:/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/support-v4-23.4.0.pom
         file:/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/support-v4-23.4.0.jar
     Required by:
         :project:unspecified > com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 4.288 secs
undefined
```

What is the problem?

How can i build my app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-platform-issues/issues/107

Please update all SDK modules (must have Android Support Repository v 32)